# JNI - Package both 64-bit and 32-bit DLLs for Windows

Tags: java, java-native-interface

I use JNI in one of my Java applications and I want to package both 64-bit and 32-bit DLLs in the product for my Windows users. Is there a way (probably a naming convention) to follow so that `System.loadLibrary("foo")` automatically knows which file should be loaded? I currently use this workaround which I do not like:

```
// try to load foo64.dll and if faild, load foo32.dll
try
{
   System.loadLibrary("foo64");
}
catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e)
{
   System.loadLibrary("foo32");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know if Vm 64bit

```
public static boolean is64BitVM() { 
        String bits = System.getProperty("sun.arch.data.model", "?");
        if (bits.equals("64")) {
            return true;
        }
        if (bits.equals("?")) {
            return System.getProperty("java.vm.name")
                    .toLowerCase().indexOf("64") >= 0;

        }
        return false;
    }
```

and then

```
static {
        fail = false;
        try { 
                if (!is64BitVM())  
                    System.loadLibrary("foo32"); //  
                else 
                    System.loadLibrary("foo64"); //               

        } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError ex) {

        }
    }
```

Comment: You can also use System.load() with an absolute path to a shared library.  I usually organize my native libraries by operating system then architecture.  Ex: lib/windows/x86_64/MyLib.dll or lib/darwin/ppc/libMyLib.dylib.  Also note that the extension used for native libraries on Darwin platforms changed from .jnilib to .dylib in >= Java 1.7.